Slicing a nested list based on other nested list
I am trying to slice sublists (arr) using elements from other sublists (slc). I am using Python. My code works just fine if there are no repeated values on the sublists to slice (arr). Otherwise, I cannot get the correct chunks.
arr[0] must be sliced with slc[0], arr[1] must be sliced with slc[1] and arr[2] must be sliced with slc[2].
Here is an example and the code I am using right now:
arr=[[5, 9, 8, 1, 0, 10, 11, 5], [13, 4, 13, 2, 5, 6, 13], [8, 25, 13, 9, 8, 7]]

slc=[[0, 5], [5, 13], [13, 7]]

rslt=[]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    rslt.append(arr[i][arr[i].index(slc[i][0]):arr[i].index(slc[i][1])+1])

current result:
rlst=[[], [], [13, 9, 8, 7]]

expected result:
rlst=[[0, 10, 11, 5], [5, 6, 13], [13, 9, 8, 7]] #expected results

My current code is not working for arr[0] and arr[1] because there are several elements from slc[0] and slc[1] on arr[0] and arr[1] respectively, so the slicing procedure is not working properly.

What if there are multiple occurrences of 5 after 0? Do you want to go to the last one or the first one?

list.index() allows you to specify the starting index to start searching from. So use the index of the first item as this argument when looking for the end index.
for a, (start, end) in zip(arr, slc):
    slice_start = a.index(start)
    slice_end = a.index(end, slice_start + 1)
    rslt.append(a[slice_start:slice_end + 1])


What Python version has list.rindex?

I made a bad guess that it would have it because str.rindex exists.

arr=[ [5, 9, 8, 1, 0, 10, 11, 5], [13, 4, 13, 2, 5, 6, 13], [8, 25, 13, 9, 8, 7]]

slc=[[0, 5] , [5, 13], [13, 7]]

rslt=[]

for i, x in enumerate(arr):

    # start index
    st_idx = x.index(slc[i][0])

    # create a sub list from start index to rest of the list
    sub = x[st_idx:]    
    
    # end index is taken from the sublist
    end = sub.index(slc[i][1])

    # end index is taken as end + 1 as you need end value to be in the list
    rslt.append(sub[:end+1])

print(rslt)

# Output : [[0, 10, 11, 5], [5, 6, 13], [13, 9, 8, 7]]

